# Find a normal form using beta reduction

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

Given the following expression :

```
((λx.λx.xx) (λx.xzx)) (λy.yy)
```

I want to find its normal form using beta reduction.

My calculation :

```
((λx.λx.xx) (λx.xzx)) (λy.yy) ->
((λx.xzx)(λx.xzx)) (λy.yy) -> ((λx.xzx)z(λx.xzx)) (λy.yy) ->
(zzz (λx.xzx)) (λy.yy) -> ?
```

But how can I continue from here :

```
(zzz (λx.xzx)) (λy.yy) -> ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Might be better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\` to represent `λ`:

```
((\x.\x.xx) (\x.xzx)) (\y.yy) =
= ((*\x*.\x.xx) *(\x.xzx)*) (\y.yy) =
= (\x.( (\x.xzx) (\x.xzx) )) (\y.yy) =
= (\x.( (*\x*.xzx) *(\x.xzx)* )) (\y.yy) =
= (\x.( (\x.xzx) z (\x.xzx) )) (\y.yy) =
= (\x.( ( (\x.xzx) z) (\x.xzx) )) (\y.yy) =
= (\x.( ( (*\x*.xzx) *z*) (\x.xzx) )) (\y.yy) =
= (\x.( ( (zzz) (\x.xzx) ) (\y.yy) =
= (*\x*.( ( (zzz) *(\x.xzx)* ) (\y.yy) =
= (zzz) (\x.( (\y.yy) z (\y.yy) )) =
= (zzz) (\x.( ((\y.yy) z) (\y.yy) )) =
= (zzz) (\x.( ((*\y*.yy) *z*) (\y.yy) )) =
= (zzz) (\x.( (zz) (\y.yy) )) =
= (zzz) (\x.(zz)(\y.yy))
```

And there's no further application available here -- at least, as long as you don't have definitions for `z`.

Notice, also, that there is an `x` definition in the final expansion, which you might've suppressed during your calculations.

All the variables (**λx** . **λx** . xx) have in common in the expression:

```
((*λx*.*λx*.xx) (λx.xzx)) (λy.yy)
```

are their names. They're different variables nonetheless.

Comment: Aha ! There is no normal form for the given expression ! I've changed the variables' names and ran into infinite loop ! Thanks .